# Django migration issues on production

Tags: django, migration

Conflicts occurring in migration files, Is it needed to commit the migration files or not? Is it needed to run makemigrations? (python,django 2.11)

Answer (score 6):

Migrations are code. They must be in the repository. Don't generate migrations on server. On your developer machine only and don't forget to commit them. It's important to follow the rule: each commit that contains any model changes must contains appropriate migrations. Then when deploying you need to apply ones.
In other words, when someone pulls your code and runs `manage.py makemigrations` he or she doesn't produce any new migarions.

Comment: Thankyou for replying. What are the steps to be followed on production server when you have changes in the code?run the `makemigrations` on local and then applying those migrations on server?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I'm using django 2. In dev we won't commit any migration files. We put the migration folder to gitignore, so that we won't commit.
When our code is pulled to production, they run makemigrations command, so that there won't be any migration issue.
With this production will have only one file for a model, where as in dev we may have multiple migration files same modal

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you were careful before you commit the migrations on the server. You must always run makemigrations before you migrate when you are making changes to your model, perhaps try it on your local machine. Test them out on the local machine before you deploy them on the server.